# PHP at CLI with cyrillic content?

Tags: php, character-encoding, cyrillic

I need for a php script support for cyrillic characters. 
/etc/php5/cli/PHP.ini:

```
default_charset = "UTF-8"
```

My script asks values from a MySQL table (collation: utf8_general_ci) and write those values inside a php variable.

The output of the script is just "???" instead of text, so I guess there is still a problem with a wrong charset, if that MySQL value is a normal latin text, the output of that script is fine.

The website itself works fine with cyrillic letters, only at command line I have these problems.

Do I have to give some additional options at command line?

Comment: You should explain better which is the problem with the cli: which console are you using? Is it a problem with input or output? when the problem occours?

Comment: sure, sorry, I add the Output

Comment: Did you also set `mbstring.internal_encoding = UTF-8` in php.ini?

Comment: Not before, but the result is the same with `mbstring.internal_encoding = UTF-8`

Comment: Are you using windows cmd.exe? or on mac or linux?

Comment: Debian Wheezy 7.8, PHP  5.4.39, MySQL 5.5.41

Comment: Do you user an UTF-8 locale? try `echo $LANG` in console, also refer to this link https://fruit.je/utf-8

Comment: changed everything to ru_RU.UTF-8 but no difference `echo $LANG
ru_RU.UTF-8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to specify which charset has to be used when sending data from database. 
 After I add following line to my script, cyrillic characters where shown without problems. `mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'utf8');`